# Trying to add a next button to <Toolbar> of <TabbedForm> to scroll through tabs

Tags: react-admin

I want to add a next button to my TabbedForm Toolbar.

I've got as far as scrolling correctly however my input data is removed when I go back. I think it has to do something with how I have setup the button as a redux link component.

```
        <Button
            submitOnEnter={false}
            variant="outlined"
            component={Link} to={`/post/create/${index}`}
        >
            Next
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
to={{ pathname: `/post/create/${index}`, state: { skipFormReset: true } }}
```